# Installing python-pip on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip

I am new to Ubuntu server, and am trying to put TensorFlow on it. My server is running in Hyper-V, but that should not matter. It is a fresh install from today, nothing else has been put on it.

According to the instructions it is easy if I have pip installed, but somehow that is failing to install. In fact it fails before when I try to update things, so maybe that is the reason. Here is the tail output of a "sudo apt-get update":

[image]

Here is the what happens when I follow with "sudo apt-get install python-pip" or "sudo apt-get install python-pip3":

[image]

And here is some version information:

[image]

Googled about, tried a bunch of things, but somehow I am not getting through to the archives. I clearly have python3 installed, but pip seems out of reach.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is an IP6 issue on my Hyper-V host. Maybe my firewall is blocking, or I haven't enabled it or something. In any case I am now using:

`sudo apt-get update -o Aquire::ForceIPv4=true`

and that worked fine. Adding the same `-o Aquire...` option worked for installing `python3-pip` too.

I got that idea from a post in the Unix forum.